# HTML validation errors "End tag nav seen, but there were open elements." and "Unclosed element ul."

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I am in the last stages of development on my site. When I try to validate my page using w3cvalidator the following errors are displayed. However when I try to action the following below; closing the `</nav` tag this only creates more errors.

Is there a quick fix for this? Ideally, I would like my page to validate 100%.

W3c Validator Errors below.

> Error
>   End tag nav seen, but there were open elements.
>   From line 41, column 9; to line 41, column 14
>
> ```
> >↩        </nav>↩
> ```

> Error
>   Unclosed element ul.
>   From line 33, column 11; to line 33, column 43
>
> ```
> <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">↩
> ```

**Here is my HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>DB Plumbing | Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/3a2264e344.js"></script>
  <script src="html9shiv.js"></script>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="wrench.png"/>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="desciption" content = "Darran Brady Plumbing">
  <meta name="keywords" content = "Plumbing, Boilers, Showers, Central Heating, Kitchens, Bathrooms, Installations, Landlord Services, Horsham, West Sussex, Sussex,Barns Green, Billingshurst,Broadbridge Heath,Christ's Hospital, Clemsfold, Copsale,Colgate,Cowfold, Faygate, Handcross, Horsham, Itchingfield, Kingsfold,Lambs Farm,Lower Beeding,Mannings Heath, Maplehurst, Monks Gate, Nuthurst, Partridge Green, Pease Pottage, Roffey, Rowhook, Rusper, Rudgwick, Southwater, Slinfold, Warnham ">
  <meta name = "author" content ="DB, Darran, Brady, Darran Brady">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script>
function myFunction() {
 var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
 if (x.className === "topnav") {
 x.className += " responsive";
 } else {
 x.className = "topnav";
 }
}
</script>
</head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <div id="branding">
          <h1><span class="highlight">DB</span> Plumbing</h1>
        </div>
        <nav>
          <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
            <li class="active"><a href="home9.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about9.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="services9.html">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="coverage9.html">Coverage</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact9.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="icon">
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:200%;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
        </nav>
        </div>
        </header>

    <section id="showcase">
      <div class="container">
      <h1>Local Award Winning Trader</h1>
       <h2>Call Darren | <i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="tel:+07756848657"> 07756848657</a></h2>
        <p>DB Plumbing provides a full range of general plumbing and repair services, from installing your new bathroom suite to fixing that leaking tap or joint that has been annoying you for ages. </p>

        <p>Our customer's individual requirements are important to us at DB Plumbing. We always provide quality service and products and combined with honesty has made us the first choice of many homes in the Horsham area</p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section id="newsletter">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Subscribe To Our Weekly Blog</h1>
        <form>
          <input type="email" placeholder="Subscribe today...">
          <button type="submit" class="subscribe">Subscribe</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>

  <section id="imagery">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="box">
  <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <h1>Accredited</h1>
  <p>Gas Safe Accreditted </p>
</div>
  <div class="box">
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <h1>Reputable</h1>
    <p>"25 years service experience "</p>
    </div>
      <div class="box">
        <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <h1>Local</h1>
        <p>Sussex and Surrey Countywide</p>
        </div>
        </div>
</section>

    <footer>
    <div>
      <p>Darren Brady Plumbing Copyright &copy; 2017</p>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put a `</li></ul>` before closing `</nav>`, the error message seems quite clear about that.

Comment: I think the anchor tag belongs to the li.icon element. So I would put it after that.